# req exp for picking first set of 4 alphabets

Tags: javascript

String will be like this 8201IFIX12W_TFIX12 
need to pick first 4 characters(IFIX) after numbers 8201
Then after that no check is required

[image]

In above picture case i need only **hkfi**

Comment: Good homework, what did you do so far? please post your attempts.

Comment: I Tried to gave link what i have tried . But link did'nt worked

Comment: You could take off of the `/g` at the end so it only gets the first result. (`/[a-zA-Z]{4}/`?)

Comment: `'8201IFIX12W_TFIX12'.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '').slice(0, 4).join('')`

Comment: Thankyou :) got :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only digits and capital letters, you can have something like:

```
/^\d+([A-Z]{4}).*$/.exec(s)[1]
```

This will ignore all the digits in the beginning, take exactly 4 letters as the 2nd group and ignore the rest of the string.

If you also have lower cased letters, you can add the `i` flag, or change `[A-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`.

A shorter version could be just:

```
/[A-Z]{4}/
```

And can be used like this:

```
/[A-Z]{4}/.exec(s)[0]
```

Or:

```
s.match(/[A-Z]{4}/)[0]
```

Comment: var rtc= "8201TFIX12W_IFIX13";
var eg = **rtc.match(/^([A-Z]{4}).*$/).exec(s)[1];**
console.log(eg);

Comment: can i write like mentioned above??   **.exec(s)[1]** not working

Comment: No. See updated answer. The `^` and `.*$` shouldn't be there in the shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]+([A-Za-z]{4})` this will give the four characters followed by any number.

`8201([A-Za-z]{4})` this will give the four characters followed by 8201 if you are specific about what should precede the characters.

on executing the command: `match = myRegexp.exec(myString);`
you can get the (IFIX) by using `match[1]`. (this will give the string that matches the pattern enclosed in the first parenthesis).

Comment: my problem is   **8201** is not a fixed numeric can be 5 also . after parsing the number i need first 4 characters

Comment: @SriSaiRamyaT As suggested by anvita,`[0-9]+` indicates that there will be at least 1 number before the word

Answer (score 0):

Regex will return four letter group  from  content with case insensitive.

"8201[a-zA-Z]{4}"

"8201[A-Z]{4}" # case sensitive.

import re

re.findall("8201[a-zA-Z]{4}", text) # return list of match starts with 8201.

Answer (score -1):

```
\b[0-9]*[A-Za-z]{4}`
```

This will return four characters from word. Numbers are optional.

Ex:

```
re.findall(r"\b[0-9]*[A-Za-z]{4}", "21324dasfshjoish khsdvjhdskj 123 sdncfslkdn12321323 122343235345dsklfmdf")
```

Output :

> ['21324dasf', 'shjo', 'khsd', 'vjhd', 'sdnc', 'fslk', '122343235345dskl', 'fmdf']